# Spring AOP Doesn't Apply on Methods with Generic Type Return Values

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, spring-aop

**EDIT: Solved, its because of the double asterisks in the beginning, I copied it from The Book: Spring Microservices in Action.**

I'm trying to advise some controller methods.

This is the aspect class:

```
@Aspect
public class PBLogger {

    @Pointcut("execution(** com.sunwell.product..*.*(..))")
    public void standardMethod() {
    }

    @Around("standardMethod()")
    public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
           ...
    }

...
}
```

This is the target method, I've made sure the package name is correct.

This one doesn't work(advice method isn't called):

```
@RequestMapping(value = "resources/items", method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = "application/json"
            )
public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> getItems(
                    @RequestHeader(value="Authorization", required = false) String _auth, @RequestParam(value="systemId", required = false) Integer _i ) throws Exception 
{ ... }
```

Without the generic return type, it works:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "resources/items", method = RequestMethod.GET,
                        produces = "application/json"
                )
public void getItems(@RequestHeader(value="Authorization", required = false) String _auth, @RequestParam(value="systemId", required = false) Integer _i ) throws Exception 
{ ... }
```

It works too using the annotated pointcut instead of execution

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
public @interface Example
{
    public String msg();
}

@Aspect
public class PBLogger {


        @Pointcut("@annotation(Example)")
        public void standardMethod() {
        }

        @Around("standardMethod()")
        public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) {
           ...
        }

    ...
}

//target method:
        @RequestMapping(value = "resources/items", method = RequestMethod.GET,
                    produces = "application/json"
            )
        @Example
public ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>> getItems(
                    @RequestHeader(value="Authorization", required = false) String _auth, @RequestParam(value="systemId", required = false) Integer _ ) throws Exception 
{ ... }
```

Comment: there is a big difference between the getItems() methods. First, one has arguments and return type and second one don't. Please share the exact code.

Comment: @dassum sorry, I have edited the second getItems method. The arguments and return values are okay as long as they are not generic.

Comment: @Mideel , the question has left a lot of things for others to guess and answer. It would be easy for us to help you if the exact code that works/has issue can be shared.

Comment: Actually I looked into "Spring Microservices in Action", but AOP is not even mentioned there. So I do not think that you have your `**` from there. But I found this strange syntax used in "Spring in Action" several times.

Comment: Actually I looked into "Spring Microservices in Action", but AOP is not
even mentioned there. So I do not think that you have your `**` from
there. But I found this strange syntax used in **"Spring in Action"**
several times - unfortunately specifically in chapter 4 for which the source code ZIP does not contain anything. That is really bad luck: faulty code in the book + missing source code for that very chapter.

Comment: @Knegaex, sorry, its not Spring Microservices in Action, but its Spring in Action

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The target method signature is not the problem, generics or not. Look at my [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

**Target classes:**

Please note that you cannot put both methods into the same class because they would have the same type erasure. The compiler would complain about this.

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q60474362;

import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

import java.util.Map;

@Component
public class MyTargetClass {
  @RequestMapping(
    value = "resources/items", method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = "application/json"
  )
  public ResponseEntity<Map<String, Object>> getItems(
    @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = false) String _auth,
    @RequestParam(value = "systemId", required = false) Integer _i
  ) throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println("MyTargetClass.getItems");
    return null;
  }
}
```

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q60474362;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestHeader;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;

@Component
public class MyOtherTargetClass {
  @RequestMapping(
    value = "resources/items", method = RequestMethod.GET,
    produces = "application/json"
  )
  public void getItems(
    @RequestHeader(value = "Authorization", required = false) String _auth,
    @RequestParam(value = "systemId", required = false) Integer _i
  ) throws Exception
  {
    System.out.println("MyOtherTargetClass.getItems");
  }
}
```

**Aspect:**

Please note that `**` in your sample pointcut does not make sense, I changed it to using `*`. If `**` works you are just lucky the syntax check is not strict but my IDE actually complains as it should. Furthermore, you don't really need `my.package..*.*(..)`, `my.package..*(..)` is enough if both class and method name do not matter.

```java
package de.scrum_master.spring.q60474362;

import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class PBLogger {
  @Pointcut("execution(* de.scrum_master.spring..*(..))")
  public void standardMethod() {}

  @Around("standardMethod()")
  public Object log(ProceedingJoinPoint jp) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println(jp);
    return jp.proceed();
  }
}
```

**Spring driver application & configuration:**

```
package de.scrum_master.spring.q60474362;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@SpringBootApplication
@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy(proxyTargetClass = true)
public class Application {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    try (ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext = SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)) {
      doStuff(appContext);
    }
  }

  private static void doStuff(ConfigurableApplicationContext appContext) throws Exception {
    MyTargetClass myTargetClass = appContext.getBean(MyTargetClass.class);
    myTargetClass.getItems("x", 11);
    MyOtherTargetClass myOtherTargetClass = appContext.getBean(MyOtherTargetClass.class);
    myOtherTargetClass.getItems("y", 22);
  }
}
```

**Console log:**

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.2.RELEASE)

(...)
2020-03-02 09:00:49.712  INFO 24028 --- [           main] d.s.spring.q60474362.Application         : Started Application in 3.554 seconds (JVM running for 5.157)
execution(ResponseEntity de.scrum_master.spring.q60474362.MyTargetClass.getItems(String,Integer))
MyTargetClass.getItems
execution(void de.scrum_master.spring.q60474362.MyOtherTargetClass.getItems(String,Integer))
MyOtherTargetClass.getItems
(...)
```

If it does not work for you, then you have some other problem such as the problematic target class not being picked up by component scan, e.g. due to a forgotten `@Component` annotation or whatever.

Comment: Thank you, its because the double asterisk in the beginning, it works after I remove the double asterisk, but I read somewhere that the ** indicates any method access specifier and also any return type.

Comment: Wherever you read that, it is false. Besides, would you mind accepting the answer, please?